# Can you create a presentation outline in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm taking a Microsoft PowerPoint class and I want to know if it's possible to create a LibreOffice Impress presentation outline in LibreOffice Writer. My computer has LibreOffice and it so far has the same features and functions as Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 2):

There's an "Outline" tab in LibreOffice Impress that might be useful:

[image]

I don't think it's possible to create the Impress outline directly from Writer, but copy/pasting works.

Please note LibreOffice might crash as soon as you switch to outline (or any other tab). It's a bug, but one that [can be solved](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1971469).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, and easily done:

1. Create a Writer document, and prepare the outline using the 'Heading' styles:
   use Heading 1 for the titles of individual slides, Heading 2, 3, etc for content of the slides. Heading 2 will be a main point, and heading 3 a sub-point, etc.

[image: outline in Writer]

(note: numbering will not carry over to Impress)

2. From the menu, select  File > Send > Outline to presentation (or use the HUD: press Alt, type 'outline' and select 'outline to presentation).
3. A new Impress document is created. Save, and edit.

(note: you must then only edit the Impress document, or edit the Writer document and create a new Impress document. There is no way to edit the Writer document and update the original Impress document)

Comment: i tried this method, it works, but in the slides, the text is not placed in the text area of the template. Any idea how to make it nicer ?